# How to confirm a paypal express payment after user clicks confirm on my website?

Tags: asp.net, rest, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using the paypal express pattern. How can I setup a payment, have the user go through paying it on paypal and then coming back to my website to click "confirm order" where I give a messsage to paypal the payment is "approved"?

So far, I have created a payment with intent=sale

However, as soon as the user goes through the paypal interface, the sale is complete. How can i setup up the payment where it is only complete after the user clicks a final button on my website.

I have seen a `intent` and a `state` field. I am unclear which fields and value i need to use in order to setup what i need.

Platform: ASP.NET REST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using REST, can you not use the same way as Classic/NVP API?
So, first call `Create a PayPal payment` , then use `Look up a payment resource`  which is similar to GETexpressCheckout API and then execute the [payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#execute-an-approved-paypal-payment).

Comment: I have created a payment, however, after only creating a payment, it has Type=sale and a State=completed when i lookup the transaction in paypal transactions on their sandbox website. That does not seem correct.

Comment: when you create payment using endpoint https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment the payment should not get completed

Comment: I was doing something stupid. I was executing payment to get payerinfo. I changed that to payment.get. thanks.